# Haptic feedback settings in Android 4.1.1?

Tags: settings, 4.1-jelly-bean, haptic-feedback, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

Just got a Samsung Galaxy S3 **mini** with Android 4.1.1 factory installed. The phone is not locked to any carrier. My problem is that I can not for the life of me find the setting to turn on the haptic feedback, neither for the keyboard nor other touch events (such as the menu button, etc.). I've looked through the settings menus several times without finding anything.

The actual vibration hardware is working, because if I go to Settings -> Sound -> Device Vibration it vibrates.

The only other mention of this issue I've found was one unanswered thread on the Samsung Galaxy Forums.

This is the kind of thing that makes me wonder if Google (and others) are actually trying to make things worse with every update. My HTC Nexus One running Android 2.3.6 never had any oddities like this. Only problem with that old phone is it's limited internal memory.

Comment: Have you turned keyboard vibrate on? System Settings, language and input, android keyboard clock the little settings icon on the right, vibrate on key press checked.

Comment: See [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39943) Post #7 seems to be the only fix so far, *provided* your are rooted, However, there's this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.immersion.android.autohaptic) on Play Store that may just do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks, now I at least have vibration in the keyboard. It turns out the stock Samsung keyboard does not have a vibration setting, and the phone comes without the Android keyboard. I ended up installing my trusty old Smart Keyboard Pro, now I have both vibration and arrow keys for moving the cursor (my old Nexus One had a trackball for this). Seems I'll have to live without system wide haptic feedback though, which really is a shame. It seems that every update introduces more bugs than fixes... sigh...

Answer (score 1):

`System Sounds > vibrate on touch`.

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found it and I hope it helps:

Unless you already did so, go to *Settings→Language and Input*, tap the setting icon on *Samsung keyboard*, go to *Advanced*, and uncheck *Vibration* and *Sound* -- depending on which one you want!

This works for the jellybean update ok 4.1.2 . Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Jelly Bean the setting for activating haptic feedback is hidden. But there are a couple apps that can be used to enable it:

- [Quick Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imoblife.shortcuts_plug_in), a plugin for [All-in-One Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.toolbox.full)
- [Spare Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts)

([Source](http://www.newbietechtips.com/2013/07/how-to-deactivate-haptic-feedback-on.html))